# MySQL - MAX() returns null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, max

i want to get the highest outside temperature for everyday out of my mysql database. it returns all of my data, but not the outside temperature. it's always null. Can someone help me? Here is the mysql code:

```
(SELECT MAX(tempOutside), tempInside, pressure, datetime 
 from weather 
 WHERE datetime BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
 GROUP BY MONTH(datetime), DAY(datetime));
```

It returns now:

```
null 18.4 1011 2014-01-23 00:15:04
null 19.2 1010 2014-01-24 00:00:05
null 19.6 1009 2014-01-25 13:15:02
```

Where is my error? An explanation would be nice. Thanks

**EDIT:**

I found the error. in my PHP file i wrote `$row_array['tempOutside'] = ...` After i changed the mysql code to `MAX(tempOutside) AS tempOutside, ...` it worked!

But i have a new question now. It returns now the maxOutSide temp, but the inside,pressure values and the timestamp are not the values that were recorded when the max Outside temp was recorded. How can i fix that? It should be like:  the MAX outsideTemp was recorded at 5PM - and the inside & pressure values at that time were: ...

Comment: Please show us your table.

Comment: Gazing in to my crystal ball...

Comment: Can you share your source data? `MAX` returns `null` if all the values it compares are `null` themself.

Comment: whats the best way to show my table? If i remove the MAX() it returns not null. Then it returns the correct values

Comment: i found the error. see my edit. i have a new problem now

Comment: If you have two rows with a max outside temp of 18.4 on the same day, which row do you want to return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. > It returns now the maxOutSide temp, but the inside,pressure values and the timestamp are not the values that were recorded when the max Outside temp was recorded.

   As documented under [MySQL Extensions to `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-extensions.html) (emphasis added):

   > In standard SQL, a query that includes a `GROUP BY` clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL because the `name` column in the select list does not appear in the `GROUP BY`:
   >
   > ```sql
   > SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
   >   FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
   >   WHERE o.custid = c.custid
   >   GROUP BY o.custid;
   > ```
   >
   > For the query to be legal, the `name` column must be omitted from the select list or named in the `GROUP BY` clause.
   >
   > MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause. This means that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the `GROUP BY` are the same for each group. ***The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.*** Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which values within each group the server chooses.
2. > How can i fix that?

   What you are looking for is the [group-wise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be obtained by joining the grouped results back to the table:

   ```sql
   SELECT tempOutside, tempInside, pressure, datetime
   FROM   weather w JOIN (
     SELECT   MONTH(datetime) m, DAY(datetime) d, MAX(tempOutside) t
     FROM     weather 
     WHERE    datetime BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY
                           AND CURRENT_DATE
     GROUP BY m, d
   ) t ON t.m = MONTH(w.datetime)
      AND t.d =   DAY(w.datetime)
      AND t.t = w.tempOutside
   ```